# Where can I find a compilation of all the Chida's (Rabbi Chaim Yosef David Azulai) riddles?

Tags: jewish-books, historical-figures

Did the Chida write a separate book of riddles or the few I've heard are from various different books?

Comment: If you can provide the ones you have heard, it may help potential answerers find the source(s).

Comment: Before you ask us where the Chida wrote his riddles, ask us if the Chida wrote riddles, because we do not know whether or not the Chida wrote riddles (cf. Bava Kama 55a)

Comment: @wfb This question as it implies is only intended for those who are aware that he wrote riddles.

Comment: You may be mixing up the Chida (R. Chaim Yosef David Azulai) with the Ben Ish Chai (R. Yosef Chaim of Baghdad) who did in fact write a book of riddles called Imrei Binah